# Flutter audioplayers player.seek() not working until after hot restart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-audioplayers

I'm trying to make a basic audio player in flutter and while the program works perfectly fine after a hot restart, when I initially boot up the app the slider progress bar gets reset to 0 every time I hit play, even though I have statements in the code to seek to the current time. Playing around with my print statements showed me that up until the moment and including after I use player.resume(), my currentTime variable stores the correct progress, only changing back to 0 once the player resumes and my logic for updating the currentTime while player is playing kicks in. This tells me that my seek() statements aren't going through until after a hot restart.

This is the code:

```
import 'package:pick_pro/main.dart';
import 'package:pick_pro/metronome.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color(0xFF000c24);
const Color blueGreen = Color.fromARGB(255, 121, 207, 175);

final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController _speedController = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController _hintController = TextEditingController();

class Playback extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  PlaybackState createState() => PlaybackState();
}

class PlaybackState extends State<Playback> {
  final player = AudioPlayer();

  late Duration songLength;
  Duration currentTime = Duration.zero;
  double playbackSpeed = 1;
  String assetPath = 'assets/sounds/demo_song.mp3';
  bool isPlaying = false;
  int bpm = 100;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    player.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.LOOP);

    // Set defualt song
    player.setUrl(assetPath, isLocal: true);
    songLength = const Duration(seconds: 259);

    // Listeners for changes in player states
    player.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = state == PlayerState.PLAYING;
      });
    });

    player.onDurationChanged.listen((newSongLength) {
      setState(() {
        songLength = newSongLength;
      });
    });

    player.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((newCurrentTime) {
      setState(() {
        if (isPlaying) {
          currentTime = newCurrentTime;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'PickPro',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 40.0,
            fontFamily: 'Caveat',
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: blueGreen,
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: darkBlue,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(
              height: 32,
            ),
            Text('Get Song Name from metadata', style: buttonText()),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Slider(
                min: 0,
                max: songLength.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                value: currentTime.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  currentTime = Duration(seconds: value.toInt());
                  setState(() {
                    player.pause();
                    player.seek(currentTime);
                  });
                }),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 10),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    formatTime(currentTime),
                    style: buttonText(),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    formatTime(songLength),
                    style: buttonText(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                  color: Colors.white),
              iconSize: 50,
              onPressed: () {
                if (isPlaying) {
                  setState(() {
                    player.pause();
                  });
                } else {
                  setState(() {
                    player.resume();
                    print(formatTime(currentTime));
                  });
                }
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Slider(
                min: 0.5,
                max: 1.5,
                value: playbackSpeed,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  playbackSpeed = double.parse(value.toStringAsFixed(2));
                  player.pause();
                  player.setPlaybackRate(playbackSpeed);
                  setState(() {});
                }),
            Center(
              child: Text(
                'Speed: ${playbackSpeed}x',
                style: buttonText(),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                        width: 120,
                        height: 30,
                        child: TextField(
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            controller: _hintController,
                            enabled: false,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                hintText: 'Song BPM:',
                                hintStyle:
                                    TextStyle(color: blueGreen, fontSize: 24),
                                filled: true,
                                fillColor: Colors.transparent,
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero),
                            cursorColor: Colors.white,
                            onSubmitted: (String value) {})),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 60.0,
                      height: 30.0,
                      child: TextField(
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        controller: _controller,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: blueGreen,
                          fontSize: 24.0,
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: '${bpm}',
                            hintStyle:
                                const TextStyle(color: blueGreen, fontSize: 24),
                            alignLabelWithHint: true,
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.transparent,
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero),
                        cursorColor: Colors.white,
                        onSubmitted: (String value) {
                          _controller.clear();
                          try {
                            bpm = int.parse(value);
                            setState(() {});
                          } catch (e) {
                            ErrorPopup.show(
                                context, "The BPM you entered is invalid.");
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                        width: 145,
                        height: 30,
                        child: TextField(
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            controller: _hintController,
                            enabled: false,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                hintText: 'Desired BPM:',
                                hintStyle:
                                    TextStyle(color: blueGreen, fontSize: 24),
                                filled: true,
                                fillColor: Colors.transparent,
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero),
                            cursorColor: Colors.white,
                            onSubmitted: (String value) {})),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 60.0,
                      height: 30.0,
                      child: TextField(
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        controller: _speedController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: blueGreen,
                          fontSize: 24.0,
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: '${bpm * playbackSpeed}',
                            hintStyle:
                                TextStyle(color: blueGreen, fontSize: 24),
                            alignLabelWithHint: true,
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.transparent,
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero),
                        cursorColor: Colors.white,
                        onSubmitted: (String value) {
                          _controller.clear();
                          try {
                            int newBPM = int.parse(value);
                            playbackSpeed =
                                double.parse((newBPM / bpm).toStringAsFixed(2));
                            player.pause();
                            player.setPlaybackRate(playbackSpeed);
                            setState(() {});
                          } catch (e) {
                            ErrorPopup.show(
                                context, "The BPM you entered is invalid.");
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      drawer: MyDrawer(index: 3),
    );
  }

  String formatTime(Duration duration) {
    // Format single integers to 2 digits long (i.e. 02)
    String formatDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, '0');

    final hours = formatDigits(duration.inHours);
    final minutes = formatDigits(duration.inMinutes);
    final seconds = formatDigits(
        duration.inSeconds - 60 * (duration.inSeconds / 60).floor());

    List<String> time = [];

    if (duration.inHours > 0) {
      time.add(hours);
    }

    time.add(minutes);
    time.add(seconds);
    return time.join(':');
  }
}
```

I don't know what to try as seek() is built into the audioplayers plugin. It works after a hot restart, I just don't know if it'll work on iOS or Android.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new var updates its duration Postion to player current position
and then add seek time to the var and update the player.

```
Duration newPos = Duration.zero;
var posFu = audioPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
posFu.then((value) {
   newPos = value! + const Duration(milliseconds: -9000);
     setState(() {
        currentPosition = newPos;
       });           
   audioPlayer.seek(newPos);
 });
```